# How to feed the output back to the input in LSTM?

Tags: keras, lstm

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(512, input_dim = 4, return_sequences = True))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(4)))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

The input here is the one hot representation of a string and the dictionary size is set to be 4.
In other word, there are four types of chars in this string.
 The output here is the probabilities that the next char ought to be.

If the length of input sequence is 1, the output dimension is 4 by 1.
 I just wonder could I feed the output back to the input and get an arbitrary length of output sequence (illustrated as follows). 
It may not be reasonable to plug back the probabilities but I just want to know the possibility to implement this one-to-many structure in keras, including the updated training process..

Example:

```
input1 -(LSTM)-> output1
output1 -(LSTM) -> output2
output2 - (LSTM) -> output3
```

We could get a 4 by 3 output in the end.

Comment: Did you manage to do it? I am curious about the training performance of your training when you feed the output of the previous step as the input of the next step during the training

Comment: Actually I got an answer from the developer of Keras which was deleted by the stackoverflow administrator. Please refer to https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/4068. For this task, I don't really implement anything since I switched to another direction. Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: @Wayne I was stuck on the similar problem and I'm relatively new to keras. If you managed to do it, maybe you can post it on the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654368/modified-one-to-many-many-to-many-in-keras) I asked. I wonder why that was deleted by the admin. I tried to look into the 4068 issue, but seems like the hint is in the DreamyRNN script, but the implementation is still not clear to me, I don't think `go_backwards` or `unroll` is relevant in this case.

Comment: @Sam In fact, I gived up Keras since then because of its intrinsic constraints. If you want to reproduce some standard models, Keras is competitive. Otherwise choose TensorFlow, PyTorch or other basic libraries instead. In TensorFlow, you can implement LSTM from scratch using tf.tensorarray and you can just make changes around it.